# trap command explanation

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Can anyone explain how "`TRAP`" command works in a script with a simple example

Comment: https://www.shellscript.sh/trap.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A trap will execute some code when a signal is caught. A quick example using the pseudo-signal EXIT:

```
$ bash
$ function say_goodbye { echo "Good bye"; }
$ trap say_goodbye EXIT
$ exit
Good bye
```

Ctrl-C sends the INT signal, so:

```
$ bash
$ function ctrl_c_handler { echo "Bang"; }
$ trap ctrl_c_handler INT
$ ^CBang
```

`^C` is where I hit Ctrl-C at a bash prompt.

Comment: Since traps are unpredictable, avoid modifying them during program execution. Declare them at the beginning.